# Configure Apache ActiveMQ programmatically

Tags: java, maven, jms, activemq-classic, message-queue

I am using Apache ActiveMQ to queue a large amount of messages and then dequeue them at the end of day. I am confused about the ActiveMQ's way of functioning, though. On my PC I have not installed ActiveMQ as a service, neither I have a server installation somewhere. I have just included the "activemq-all-5.14.5.jar" as a Maven dependency on my project and I am using the following code so far:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws URISyntaxException, Exception {
    BrokerService broker = BrokerFactory.createBroker(new URI("broker:(tcp://localhost:4848)"));
    broker.start();
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        // Producer
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:4848");
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue queue = session.createQueue("customerQueue");
        String payload = "Important Task";
        Message msg = session.createTextMessage(payload);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        System.out.println("Sending text '" + payload + "'");
        msg.setLongProperty("_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY", System.currentTimeMillis() + 5000L);
        producer.send(msg);

        // Consumer
        MessageConsumer consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);
        connection.start();
        QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(queue);
        while (browser.getEnumeration().hasMoreElements()) {
            TextMessage textMsg = (TextMessage) consumer.receive();
            browser.getEnumeration().nextElement();
            System.out.println(textMsg);
            System.out.println("Received: " + textMsg.getText());
        }

        session.close();
    } finally {
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
        broker.stop();
    }
}
```

As you can see, I want to delay a message by 5 seconds (or more, that could vary) but in every guide I've found, I am instructed to configure the XML Configuration file. But, this is a file that is used when you run the ActiveMQ as a service. I am currently employing **just the jar library**.

Initially, I have installed Glassgfish server in order to use JMS so as to queue all messages but since then I have abandoned the project but the IP is still being used from ActiveMQ (localhost:4848).

Note that the following is a perfectly working example -KahaDB is also being used to store the messages in case of a server failure.

As far as I am concerned, ActiveMQ does start a local server from the STS that I am running this code but where is the configuration file? Can I change its properties **programmatically**?

Comment: Did you try something like `broker.setSchedulerSupport(true)`? (see http://activemq.apache.org/maven/5.11.0/apidocs/org/apache/activemq/broker/BrokerService.html#setSchedulerSupport(boolean))

Comment: I just did, it didn't work.

Comment: Are you sure about the `_AMQ_SCHED_DELIVERY` property you use? ActiveMQ property would rather be something like `AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY` (see http://activemq.apache.org/delay-and-schedule-message-delivery.html)

Comment: Thanks for your answers. I changed the property back to the default `ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY` (while also configuring the value so as to point to the milliseconds) but still does not delay the message.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This should work (works for we with ActiveMQ 5.12.3). Be sure to clean your KahaDB store first, to avoid previous messages to be read.

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    BrokerService broker = BrokerFactory.createBroker(new URI("broker:(tcp://localhost:4848)"));
    broker.setSchedulerSupport(true);
    broker.start();
    Connection connection = null;
    try {
        // Producer
        ConnectionFactory connectionFactory = new ActiveMQConnectionFactory("tcp://localhost:4848");
        connection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        Session session = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        Queue queue = session.createQueue("customerQueue");
        String payload = "Important Task";
        Message msg = session.createTextMessage(payload);
        MessageProducer producer = session.createProducer(queue);
        System.out.println("Sending text '" + payload + "'");
        msg.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, 5000L);
        producer.send(msg);
        connection.start();

        // Consumer
        MessageConsumer consumer = null;
        consumer = session.createConsumer(queue);

        QueueBrowser browser = session.createBrowser(queue);
        while (browser.getEnumeration().hasMoreElements()) {
            TextMessage textMsg = (TextMessage) consumer.receive();
            browser.getEnumeration().nextElement();
            System.out.println(textMsg);
            System.out.println("Received: " + textMsg.getText());
        }

        session.close();
    } finally{
        if (connection != null) {
            connection.close();
        }
        broker.stop();
    }
}
```

The first clean run (with an empty KahaDB store) should not output

> "Received: Important Task"

, whereas the second will, if you do not delete the data files in between.

Removing the line `

> msg.setLongProperty(ScheduledMessage.AMQ_SCHEDULED_DELAY, 5000L);

would make the first clean run output "Received: Important Task"